# How to grant CreateRepository permission to create wikis in TFS Azure DevOps?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I want to create Wiki using our TFS account (free account), we use Team Foundation Version Control not Git, but when I try to create wiki I get the error:

> TF401027: You need the Git 'CreateRepository' permission to perform
>   this action. Details: identity 'Windows Live ID\id@hotmail.com', scope
>   'project'.

Comment: I didn't do anything and the wiki page opened with its editor normally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, Wiki is stored as a Git repository in your Azure DevOps project. You can find more information describing the issue you're facing in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-create-repo?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#provision-a-wiki-git-repository).

Here is the snippet:

> On the Wiki landing page, choose Create Wiki to provision a new Git repository that will store all your wiki pages and related artifacts. (Even if you use TFVC for source control, you can create a wiki with a Git repository.)
>
> ...
>
> You can contact your administrator to provision the Wiki Git repository or request that they elevate your permissions. Stakeholders can't be granted permissions to create a wiki as they have no permissions to work in Repos or Code.